# que evento debo usar al cambiar las dimensiones de un elemento en el DOM

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("scroll", function () {
 console.log("scroll Event...");
});
function WrapText() {
 document.getElementById("container").classList.add("WrapText");
}
```

```css
div {
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background-color:yellow;
 overflow: auto;
}
div.WrapText{
 height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</div>
<button onClick="WrapText()">Wrap Text</button>
```

Cuando hago `Scroll` lo detecto a través del evento **onScroll** y despliego un mensaje en consola.

Ahora, cuando pulso el botón `Wrap Text` re dimensiono la ventana y la ajusto al texto.

**El problema:**
Como detectar el evento de re dimensionamiento de una `<div>` a través de `addEventListener()`, es decir, como saber cuando re dimensiono un elemento en el **DOM**?

**NOTA:**
Es importante que la solución sea a través de un evento anexo al elemento `<div id="container">` tal como hacemos con el evento **onScroll** y no por el evento **onClick** aplicado al elemento `<button>`.

Comment: Pretendes detectar con un evento cuando el elemento con id **container** cambie de tamaño? Porque de ser así, ya te aviso de que un elemento div no dispara ningún evento **"resize"**.

Comment: Hice la pregunta en SO y si es posible (todo es posible): [How to know when you change the dimensions of an element in the DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44032115/how-to-know-when-you-change-the-dimensions-of-an-element-in-the-dom)

Comment: ajjajajaj yo NO he dicho que sea generalizadamente imposible, solo he dicho que no se puede usar el evento resize como si fuese la ventana del navegador. Claro que todo es posible.

Comment: Bueno, realmente no haz dicho nada, ahora si tienes algo que aportar que pueda ayudar a resolver lo que aquí se plantea eres libre de compartirlo,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe un método muy eficiente para detectar el evento que comentas. Puedes encontrar el plugin en el siguiente enlace.

http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/

Esta librería tiene una clase llamada ResizeSensor que puede ser usada para la detección de redimensiones.

Ejemplo:

```
new ResizeSensor(jQuery('#divId'), function(){ 
    console.log('content dimension changed');
});
```

Otra opción que puedes utilizar el MutationObserver. La documentación la puedes encontrar en el siguiente enlace: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver. A continuación un ejemplo:

```js
// Selecciona el nodo
var target = document.getElementById('some-id');
  
// Crea al instancia del observador
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
     alert("change");

        // Deja de observar
     observer.disconnect();
 });    
});
  
// Configura el observador
var config = {
 attributes: true
};
  
// Pasa la opciones y el target al inicio de la observación
observer.observe(target, config);

setTimeout(function(){
 document.getElementById('some-id').style.height = "200px"
}, 3000);
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="some-id" style="height:20px; width:20px; background-color:red">
    </div>
</body>
```

No utilices el plugin jQuery onresize, es muy lento debido que se basa en iteraciones con timeout, algo que es increíblemente lento.

Comment: +1 Hector - Gracias por tu respuesta sin embargo hay un Web Api [MutationObserver()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) que plantea una solución adecuada a mi pregunta, si te parece mejora tu respuesta incluyendo esta opción y calificare tu respuesta como aceptada, Saludos!! ;)...